# Git rebase feature branch to another branch

Tags: git

I have forked repo `A`. I have pulled it locally and checked out branch `b1`.
I have created a new feature branch of `b1` (and not master):

```
git checkout -b my-feature b1
```

I have made a PR and pushed my changes to my own forked branch.

1 month has passed, my PR isn't merged yet, now I need to do a rebase, how do I do it?

I need to rebase to `b1` and not master.

I have tried the following:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/b1
```

but it keeps saying

```
Current branch my-feature is up to date.
```

Comment: Why do you "need to do a rebase"? Rebasing is rarely needed, I would say. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And with a `git fetch` or `git pull --rebase origin b1`

Comment: @sintax I'm not rally sure, i'm told to do a rebase. I think at this points my PR has conflicts with the latest b1 branch and they want to fix it

Comment: @mickaelw didn't help

Comment: @Joe, what you want to do is probably merge the changes to the b1 branch into you local branch, then issue your PR. So, something like ```git merge b1 ``` while you're in your feature branch

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
git checkout my-feature
git pull origin b1 --rebase
```

The later command will pull the new commits of b1 branch from the remote (origin) and will make your current branch rebase onto that. You might run into some merge conflicts during the rebase which you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git checkout my-feature
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/b1
```

If it doesn't work, check if there really are new commits in origin/b1 that should be included into your my-feature branch.